# Problem with one of the premises in electrostatic pressure theory

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I was watching a video and he was trying to derive a result in electrostatic pressure. He was deriving the pressure on a differential area element of a hollow conducting sphere. He did it two ways, the second way was straightforward he did it by using only gauss's law and a neat argument but the first derivation I have a problem. I have the video linked with the time stamp. https://youtu.be/kRMTZNRULcQ?t=200 . Isn't Electric Field anywhere inside the conductor zero. So there will be no electric field inside the thickness of the conductor. But he managed to integrate it somehow? he considered electric field to be changing inside the conductor that has density rho and did it. But proprties of conductors state that elctric field inside conductor is zero, doesn't it? [image]

Comment: The video at the point of your link says that an electric field is applied to an infinite sheet of charge. It doesn't say that the charge is in a conductor.